# Is it possible to use Appium to automate an iOS application on a Windows machine?

Tags: automated-testing, appium, mobile-automation, sdet, mobile-testing

I need to automate an iOS application with Appium, C# on a Windows PC using SauceLab. I can utilize any real-time device or emulator that is linked to saucelab. I only have a Windows computer here. Is there any chance, and if so, how?